# Should one word that is easily editable force an otherwise constructive answer to be closed?

Tags: discussion

The guidelines to stack exchange say that information that helps answer a question should be posted in the form of an answer, rather than in the form of a comment. The guidelines also indicate that neither answers nor comments should be used to say "Thanks!"

But does that mean that an otherwise constructive answer should be arbitrarily closed because the writer tacks a "Thanks!" onto the end of the answer?

It took all of five seconds for me to edit out the "Thanks!" at the end of this answer to the question: [Why does my Nikon D7200 + YN-622 TX have a one second delay when firing a studio flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85572/why-does-my-nikon-d7200-yn-622-tx-have-a-one-second-delay-when-firing-a-studio)

[image: Edited answer]

It seems to me that the answer was constructive and told us *exactly* what the issue was for the user who posted the question. Yet because the answer was summarily closed by a mod, it can't even be nominated for undeletion.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine for the OP to post an answer to his own question.  But WayneF's answer gives five possible causes for the problem, and already stated red eye sync is the most likely culprit, so the answer doesn't add anything new.  And I don't think it was intended as an answer proper, more of a thank you and confirmation of which of Wayne's suggestions had worked.

If another user had posted that as an answer, we'd be asking why they did so, when WayneF's more comprehensive answer already addressed red eye sync, right?

I would probably have converted it to a comment, but there already is a comment saying the same thing - not sure what the order of things was, but we don't need both for sure, and IMO it's more acceptable as a comment.  I don't think it was purely because of the word "Thanks!" that it was deleted.

On a wider note, it is amazing how many people will comment on a misspelling or obvious mistake rather than clicking edit and fixing it.  Or questioning tag choices when they can simply re-tag the question themselves.  So in general I'd like to see people being a bit more proactive and just fixing stuff rather than discussing or complaining about it.  For sure.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having more than one answer even if they will be inferior.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is still useful to allow the OP to post an answer that confirms exactly what the problem was and how it was solved. Such an answer is not without precedent here, even when other answer(s) have already listed the issue among other possibilities.

In the other existing answer the problem was listed as one among several that *might* be the culprit. In the OP's answer it is presented as *the issue* that was solved. Leaving that information in a comment to the previous answer (which appears to have been made around the same time the OP's answer was deleted) makes it subject to the transience of comments as opposed to answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see no point in deleting an answer which does not meet academical standards of SE. There was an answer recently which looked somewhat like this one in review queue, skipped and upvoted it because it was containing useful information.

Having more than one answer is fine too.